# How to overlap UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, overlap

[image]

If you look at the screenshot you will notice that each UITableViewCell are 20% overlapped from top portion to the upper tableview cell.

Is there any way we can overlap cells ?

Comment: I really appreciate if you take part in suggesting idea for the implementation instead of just pointing out. For your info I have tried with http://i.stack.imgur.com/uSHXS.png this kind of stuffs but it will not work cause i have certain other animations which will expand the gaps between cells. Thank you

Comment: @Tariq-iPHONEProgrammer - You should mention your all requirements in your question because if some one answers he will give answer what you asked in your question.... He dont know what you have extra to do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I never tried it, but this kind of logic will work. Remember, you won't get any touch in the overlapped area.

1) Add your subview to `cell.contentView`, make sure subview height is greater than `rowHeight` of your tableView.

```
float overlapHeight  = 10.0;

subView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, -10.0, 
                  your_subview_width, rowHeight + overlapHeight);
```

2) Add this code, so that your cell won't clip contents outside its frame

```
cell.clipsToBounds = NO;
cell.contentView.clipsToBounds = NO;
```

3) Now your cell's will overlap, but there will be a clip mark around the borders of the cell. To avoid that implement willDisplayCell delegate function

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    cell.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
}
```

Comment: Yes who down vote he should explain why he did that other wise he is just playing with it.

Comment: It seems like this method doesn't work in ios7? Everything is still being clipped.

Comment: Got it, Don't forget to add cell.contentView.superview.clipsToBounds = NO; (For iOS7)

Comment: In my case its working, but the views in the table are overlapping different way that I want. Is it possible to know when the cell is added to the view, so I can reorganize them?

Comment: Clever, you saved me.

Comment: cell.layer.zPosition = indexPath.row; To make current cell behind previous cell

Answer (score 1):

The overlap effect can be achieved visually by composing your cell of two parts: a narrow one on the top and a wide one on the bottom. The bottom part is simple: it is a grey rectangle with a text/image component inside. The trick is in the part on the top.

The height of the top part equals the height of the entire colored tab. Your program can put one of two images there - either a tab on top of a narrow gray strip representing the bottom of the prior cell, or a tab on top of a brown background. Inside your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` check the `row`. If it is zero, pick the image with the brown background; otherwise, pick the image with the grey strip in the background at the top.

Answer (score 0):

No need to overlap the cells. Your top cell should look like this:

[image]

and all remaining cells should look like this:

[image]

Your `tableFooterView` should just be a grey bar (the "bottom" of a cell)

Comment: I have tried this approach but the problem is you are cutting the image from the bottom. But I have certain other animation for that purpose I need complete cell image. Lets say for ex If I will touch any cell then I have to expand the gap between two cell thats why I can't crop the images :)